# LED Strip on Raspberry Pi Check if its On - Neopixel

Tags: python, pi-2, led

How can I check if the one pixel is on or not? 
Is there any function for that. I've googled but couldn't find anything helpful.

```
import board
import neopixel
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D18, 17)


def lightOnMedi():
    pixels[0] = (255, 0, 0)
    pixels[1] = (255, 0, 0)
    pixels[15] = (255, 0, 0)
    pixels[16] = (255, 0, 0)
```

My program has to trigger another method when one of the pixels (0,1,15 or 16) are turned ON.

Comment: You need to keep track of which LEDs you have switched on and off.